# PHP get url content and then parse the element in the table to JSON

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem parsing a HTML table that i'm getting from another URL and then parsing in into a json. the problem is that in my url page I have two tables and on my code it always grabs the two tables but I only want table 1 so that messes up the whole returned json

I tried some people's solutions to use " ->item (0) " but it wouldn't work for me.

```html
Hello,

I'm having a problem parsing a HTML table that i'm getting from another URL and then parsing in into a json. the problem
is that in my url page I have two tables and on my code it always grabs the two tables but I only want table 1. so that
messes up the whole returned json

<div id="d" class="div1">
    <table class="example-table" width="100%">
        <sec>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Admission Type</th>
                    <th>Facility</th>
                    <th>Facility&nbsp;Plus</th>
                    <th>All Facility</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="5">Adult<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">18-64 years</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label adult single">Single&nbsp;Admission</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no single">$111</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no single">$115</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes single">$110</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Adult<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">18-64 years</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label adult multi">Multi per visit (5+)*&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no multi">$75</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no multi">$925</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes multi">$15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Adult<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">18-64 years</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label adult monthly">Regular 1 month pass</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no monthly">$551</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no monthly">$710</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes monthly">$714</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Adult<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">18-64 years</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label adult continuous">Continuous monthly&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no continuous">$415</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no continuous">$610</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes continuous">$615</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Adult<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">18-64 years</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label adult annual">Annual&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no annual">$480</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no annual">$624</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes annual">$686</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="5">Youth/Senior<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">15-15/65+
                            years</span></td>
                    <td class="label youth-senior single">Single&nbsp;Admission</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-no tcrc-no single">$7</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-no single">$8.75</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-yes single">$9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Youth/Senior<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">15-15/65+
                            years</span></td>
                    <td class="label youth-senior multi">Multi per visit (5+)*&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-no tcrc-no multi">$6.30</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-no multi">$7.90</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-yes multi">$8.10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Youth/Senior<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">15-15/65+
                            years</span></td>
                    <td class="label youth-senior monthly">Regular 1 month pass&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-no tcrc-no monthly">$46</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-no monthly">$59</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-yes monthly">$61</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Youth/Senior<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">15-15/65+
                            years</span></td>
                    <td class="label youth-senior continuous">Continuous monthly&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-no tcrc-no continuous">$40</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-no continuous">$50</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-yes continuous">$51</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Youth/Senior<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">15-15/65+
                            years</span></td>
                    <td class="label youth-senior annual">Annual</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-no tcrc-no annual">$1414</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-no annual">$1414</td>
                    <td class="dropin-yes centres-yes tcrc-yes annual">$141</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="5">Child<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">2-10 years</span></td>
                    <td class="label child single">Single&nbsp;Admission</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no single">$44</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no single">$44</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes single">$777</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Child<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">2-10 years</span>
                    </td>

                    <td class="label child multi">Multi per visit (5+)*</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no multi">$14</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no multi">$14</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes multi">$14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Child<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">2-10 years</span>
                    </td>

                    <td class="label child monthly">Regular 1 Month Pass</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no monthly">$737</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no monthly">$746</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes monthly">$748</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Child<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">2-10 years</span>
                    </td>

                    <td class="label child continuous">Continuous monthly</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no continuous">$544</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no continuous">$450</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes continuous">$471</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Child<br><span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: .93em;">2-10 years</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="label child annual">Annual</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no annual">$785</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no annual">$785</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes annual">$6936</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="5">Family<br></td>
                    <td class="label family single">Single&nbsp;Admission</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no single">$785</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no single">$875</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes single">$52</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Family<br></td>
                    <td class="label family multi">Multi per visit (5+)*&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no multi">$000</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no multi">$120</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes multi">$2222</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Family<br></td>
                    <td class="label family monthly">Regular 1 month pass&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no monthly">$000</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no monthly">$111</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes monthly">$222</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Family<br></td>
                    <td class="label family continuous">monthly&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no continuous">$000</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no continuous">$111</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes continuous">$222</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Family<br></td>
                    <td class="label family annual">Annual&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=" centres-no tcrc-no annual">$000</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-no annual">$111</td>
                    <td class=" centres-yes tcrc-yes annual">$222</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </sec>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="contactListing">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Online</th>
            <td><a title="Contact" href="#" class="#">Contact Us Online</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table data-updated="" summary="Contact information">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Telephone</th>
            <td>
                <p><br />Outside City: 414141414</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">TTY</th>
            <td>121212425</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Email</th>
            <td><a href="mailto:44@gmail.com">44@gmail.com</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is my php code

```js
<?php
try {
    error_reporting(0);

 $htmlContent = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/samir/table.html");
  
 $DOM = new DOMDocument();
 $DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent); 

 $Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
 $Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
 //#Get header name of the table
 
 
 foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
 {
  $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
 }
  
 //#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
 $i = 0;
 $j = 0;
 foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
 {
  $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
  $i = $i + 1;
  $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
 }
 //print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();
 
 //#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
 for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
 {
  for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
  {
   $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
  }
 }
 $aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData; unset($aTempData);
 print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 }
```

```js
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Category] => $10.35 [Admission Type] => Adult18-64 years [Facility] => Regular 1 month pass [Facility Plus] => $55 [All Facility] => $70 [Online] => Adult18-64 years [Telephone] => Multi per visit (5+)*  [TTY] => $7.45 [Email] => $9.25 ) [1] => Array ( [Category] => $624 [Admission Type] => $686 [Facility] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Facility Plus] => Single Admission [All Facility] => $7 [Online] => $65 [Telephone] => Adult18-64 years [TTY] => Annual  [Email] => $480 ) [2] => Array ( [Category] => $46 [Admission Type] => $59 [Facility] => $61 [Facility Plus] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [All Facility] => Continuous monthly  [Online] => $7.90 [Telephone] => $8.10 [TTY] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Email] => Regular 1 month pass  ) [3] => Array ( [Category] => Single Admission [Admission Type] => $5.50 [Facility] => $7 [Facility Plus] => $7.25 [All Facility] => Child2-10 years [Online] => $408 [Telephone] => $520 [TTY] => $530 [Email] => Child2-10 years ) [4] => Array ( [Category] => Child2-10 years [Admission Type] => Continuous monthly [Facility] => $29 [Facility Plus] => $40 [All Facility] => $41 [Online] => Regular 1 Month Pass [Telephone] => $37 [TTY] => $46 [Email] => $48 ) [5] => Array ( [Category] => $31.50 [Admission Type] => Family [Facility] => Multi per visit (5+)*  [Facility Plus] => $19.80 [All Facility] => $24.30 [Online] => Family [Telephone] => Single Admission [TTY] => $22 [Email] => $27 ) [6] => Array ( [Category] => $161 [Admission Type] => $188 [Facility] => Family [Facility Plus] => Annual  [All Facility] => $1308 [Online] => $218 [Telephone] => Family [TTY] => Continuous monthly   [Email] => $123 ) [7] => Array ( [Category] => $110 [Admission Type] => Adult18-64 years [Facility] => Multi per visit (5+)*  [Facility Plus] => $75 [All Facility] => $925 [Online] => Adult18-64 years [Telephone] => Single Admission [TTY] => $111 [Email] => $115 ) [8] => Array ( [Category] => $610 [Admission Type] => $615 [Facility] => Adult18-64 years [Facility Plus] => Annual  [All Facility] => $480 [Online] => $714 [Telephone] => Adult18-64 years [TTY] => Continuous monthly  [Email] => $415 ) [9] => Array ( [Category] => $6.30 [Admission Type] => $7.90 [Facility] => $8.10 [Facility Plus] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [All Facility] => Regular 1 month pass  [Online] => $8.75 [Telephone] => $9 [TTY] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Email] => Multi per visit (5+)*  ) [10] => Array ( [Category] => Annual [Admission Type] => $1414 [Facility] => $1414 [Facility Plus] => $141 [All Facility] => Child2-10 years [Online] => $40 [Telephone] => $50 [TTY] => $51 [Email] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years ) [11] => Array ( [Category] => Child2-10 years [Admission Type] => Regular 1 Month Pass [Facility] => $737 [Facility Plus] => $746 [All Facility] => $748 [Online] => Multi per visit (5+)* [Telephone] => $14 [TTY] => $14 [Email] => $14 ) [12] => Array ( [Category] => $6936 [Admission Type] => Family [Facility] => Single Admission [Facility Plus] => $785 [All Facility] => $875 [Online] => Child2-10 years [Telephone] => Annual [TTY] => $785 [Email] => $785 ) [13] => Array ( [Category] => $111 [Admission Type] => $222 [Facility] => Family [Facility Plus] => monthly   [All Facility] => $000 [Online] => $2222 [Telephone] => Family [TTY] => Regular 1 month pass  [Email] => $000 ) [14] => Array ( [Category] => [Admission Type] => [Facility] => [Facility Plus] => [All Facility] => [Online] => $111 [Telephone] => $222 [TTY] => [Email] => ) )
```

```js
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Category] => Adult18-64 years [Admission Type] => Single Admission [Facility] => $111 [Facility Plus] => $115 [All Facility] => $110 ) [1] => Array ( [Category] => Adult18-64 years [Admission Type] => Multi per visit (5+)*  [Facility] => $75 [Facility Plus] => $925 [All Facility] => $15 ) [2] => Array ( [Category] => Adult18-64 years [Admission Type] => Regular 1 month pass [Facility] => $551 [Facility Plus] => $710 [All Facility] => $714 ) [3] => Array ( [Category] => Adult18-64 years [Admission Type] => Continuous monthly  [Facility] => $415 [Facility Plus] => $610 [All Facility] => $615 ) [4] => Array ( [Category] => Adult18-64 years [Admission Type] => Annual  [Facility] => $480 [Facility Plus] => $624 [All Facility] => $686 ) [5] => Array ( [Category] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Admission Type] => Single Admission [Facility] => $7 [Facility Plus] => $8.75 [All Facility] => $9 ) [6] => Array ( [Category] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Admission Type] => Multi per visit (5+)*  [Facility] => $6.30 [Facility Plus] => $7.90 [All Facility] => $8.10 ) [7] => Array ( [Category] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Admission Type] => Regular 1 month pass  [Facility] => $46 [Facility Plus] => $59 [All Facility] => $61 ) [8] => Array ( [Category] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Admission Type] => Continuous monthly  [Facility] => $40 [Facility Plus] => $50 [All Facility] => $51 ) [9] => Array ( [Category] => Youth/Senior15-15/65+ years [Admission Type] => Annual [Facility] => $1414 [Facility Plus] => $1414 [All Facility] => $141 ) [10] => Array ( [Category] => Child2-10 years [Admission Type] => Single Admission [Facility] => $44 [Facility Plus] => $44 [All Facility] => $777 ) [11] => Array ( [Category] => Child2-10 years [Admission Type] => Multi per visit (5+)* [Facility] => $14 [Facility Plus] => $14 [All Facility] => $14 ) [12] => Array ( [Category] => Child2-10 years [Admission Type] => Regular 1 Month Pass [Facility] => $737 [Facility Plus] => $746 [All Facility] => $748 ) [13] => Array ( [Category] => Child2-10 years [Admission Type] => Continuous monthly [Facility] => $544 [Facility Plus] => $450 [All Facility] => $471 ) [14] => Array ( [Category] => Child2-10 years [Admission Type] => Annual [Facility] => $785 [Facility Plus] => $785 [All Facility] => $6936 ) [15] => Array ( [Category] => Family [Admission Type] => Single Admission [Facility] => $785 [Facility Plus] => $875 [All Facility] => $52 ) [16] => Array ( [Category] => Family [Admission Type] => Multi per visit (5+)*  [Facility] => $000 [Facility Plus] => $120 [All Facility] => $2222 ) [17] => Array ( [Category] => Family [Admission Type] => Regular 1 month pass  [Facility] => $000 [Facility Plus] => $111 [All Facility] => $222 ) [18] => Array ( [Category] => Family [Admission Type] => monthly   [Facility] => $000 [Facility Plus] => $111 [All Facility] => $222 ) [19] => Array ( [Category] => Family [Admission Type] => Annual  [Facility] => $000 [Facility Plus] => $111 [All Facility] => $222 ) )
```

the second set of results i'm getting it only when i have one table in the page.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are just extracting all of the `<th>` and `<td>` tags without limiting it to any table.

So you could instead start this search in the first table of the form...

```
$table1 = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
$Header = $table1->getElementsByTagName('th');
$Detail = $table1->getElementsByTagName('td');
```